# Docker inside LXC unprivileged container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, lxc, apparmor

I am trying to run Docker containers inside LXC unprivileged container. Can anyone suggest what am I missing?

If I remove apparmor from the LXC container it works fine. Seems like I need to do some apparmor magic to make it work without disabling apparmor?

This is my current LXC container config:

```
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/nesting.conf

# Distribution configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/common.conf

# For Ubuntu 14.04
lxc.mount.entry = /sys/kernel/debug sys/kernel/debug none bind,optional 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /sys/kernel/security sys/kernel/security none bind,optional 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /sys/fs/pstore sys/fs/pstore none bind,optional 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = mqueue dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime,create=dir,optional 0 0
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/userns.conf

# For Ubuntu 14.04
lxc.mount.entry = /sys/firmware/efi/efivars sys/firmware/efi/efivars none bind,optional 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc none bind,optional 0 0
lxc.arch = linux64

# Container specific configuration
lxc.idmap = u 0 1258512 65536
lxc.idmap = g 0 1258512 65536
lxc.rootfs.path = dir:/var/lib/lxc/ubuntu/rootfs
lxc.uts.name = ubuntu

# Network configuration
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.link = br0
lxc.net.0.link = lxcbr0
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:3e:3f:77
lxc.net.0.ipv4.address = 10.0.3.242/24
lxc.net.0.ipv4.gateway = auto
lxc.cgroup.memory.limit_in_bytes = 512M
lxc.cgroup.cpuset.cpus = 0-31
lxc.start.auto = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the following in the config helpful in resolving:

```
lxc.aa_profile = unconfined
```

It may break your security profile, but may get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Well, I ended up switching to LXD and nested features seem to work much better with it. No problems anymore.